# Running a script in julia VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

this might sound like a very stupid question, but what is the difference between F5 command in julia vscode and Ctrl + Enter? I know, that F5 means start debbuging, but I just don't understand, why a script written by someone else openend in julia vscode can be executed only by the Ctrl + Enter command. Is it something like debbuging is only for some kind of projects and this is only a script?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I really don't know about VSCode, but in other editors, `Ctrl` + `Enter` is "put this line in the REPL literally and execute it", whereas `F5` evaluates the whole script, stopping at break points.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I have a script that creates a plot and when I want to see the plot, the only option is to use Ctrl + Enter. But it is kinda annoying to have to "choose" the whole text of the script and press Ctrl + Enter. Why commands like "start debugging" or "run without debugging" don't do the thing?

Comment: Ah, plotting makes an important difference. You should add that point to the question.

Comment: I can't find a corresponding answer now, but the difference is that the REPL automatically calls `display`, while in running a script, this does not happen.

Comment: It's not only that, after I tried the other commands I just executed the plot line, but got an error that the packages weren't loaded (using "the name of the package" was at the beggining of the script), is that another exception?

Comment: I suggest that you start with a plain editor and a terminal, to get an intuition for execution.

Answer (score 0):

As with all things in vs code you can run them from the command palette by pressing ctrl/cmd+shift+p and typing in “Julia” will pop out the various run commands.

As for keybinds, you can check if there is one set or set your own to run this command by managing your keyboard shortcuts. cmd/ctrl+k cmd/ctrl+s will bring up the keyboard shortcut palette.